# Why ROS2 rclc_parameter_set_int() has value parameter as int64_t while rclc_parameter_get_int() has the same parameter as int type?

Tags: ros, ros2, parameter, server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys,

I just dealt with these two functions while I was learning how to implement a Parameter Server with Micro-ROS and ROS2 Galactic. I confess it bugged my mind, so we are talking about the same parameter value transported within a Parameter Server. Exploring the library I noticed that both functions are based on the  `Parameter` struct, an heiress from `rcl_interfaces__msg__Parameter`, that has an `integer_value` member of int64_t type. Why don't use int64_t for the get and set functions?

Please, don't take it as criticism. I just wanna understand the reasons for this decision.

Cheers.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/397640/why-ros2--rclc_parameter_set_int()-has-value-parameter-as-int64_t-while-rclc_parameter_get_int()-has-the-same-parameter-as-int-type?/) by [Jefecito](https://answers.ros.org/users/30205/jefecito/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2022-03-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Fixed here: https://github.com/ros2/rclc/pull/268

---

Originally posted by [Pablogs](https://answers.ros.org/users/62986/pablogs/) with karma: 443 on 2022-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jefecito](https://answers.ros.org/users/30205/jefecito/) on 2022-03-17**:
Yeah, thanks. But I saw that it could be a problem for Galactic. What kind of API incompatibility could happen?

**Comment by [Pablogs](https://answers.ros.org/users/62986/pablogs/) on 2022-03-17**:
Well, according to the C99 standard int can be anything greater than 16 bits, depending on the platform and compiler. Now we are enforcing it to be 64 bits long with int64_t... So there can be an API break.